# Apply an exam or give an exam

Tags: word-usage, collocations

If I'm a teacher and I'm going to give my students an exam tomorrow, Can I say:
 I´m going to apply an exam tomorrow?

Comment: "Give an exam" is common and correct. You can also say: I'm going to hold/offer an exam tomorrow."

Comment: When I hear *apply* I think of bandages or paint. The mental image I have when I read *apply an exam* is of somebody stapling or gluing a physical exam to somebody else . . .

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe apply would be correct usage. Could you be thinking of "administer"?

> Tomorrow I'm going to ***administer*** an exam.